# Unable to see the uploaded file on Google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using PHP and Service Account to connect and upload a test file to Google drive. It does not give me any error but when I login using my account into google drive and check for this file. I dont find it. Why? 
Please help.

I've used the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php 
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'google-api-php-client-master/src' );

require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
require_once "google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";
session_start();

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<xyz>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '<abc>-privatekey.p12';

$key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
$auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
    $key);
$client = new Google_Client();
//$client->setUseObjects(true);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = file_get_contents('My document.txt');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    ));
print_r($createdFile);

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The document you've created is tied to your service account.  You can't login to the Google Drive website with your service account.  [Explanation of service accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts) kind of explains this.  You have two options:

1. If it's important the document be visible to your service account AND a personal account,  create the document using a personal Google account and share it with your service account (via the email address).
2. Understand that the document does exist, but is only available to the service account.  In the $createdFile variable from your code sample, you will see the "downloadUrl" property.  Use this url in the code below.

   $request = new Google_Http_Request();
   $requestSigned = self::$client->getAuth()->sign($request);
   $response = self::$client->getIo()->makeRequest($requestSigned);
   $requestSigned->getResponseBody();

Using the either the [get method](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts) or the list method, you can also retrieve the "downloadUrl" at a later time for your files.